# How can I order items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

So I am trying to create a function that takes the first item in an array and adds an `a1` to the end of it, along with the next item of the array. Then, the 3rd item gets an `a2` added to it along with the fourth item, and so on. Also, I want to do this multiple times and create multiple arrays with the function parameter `orderNum`. I am having a hard time trying to find out how to do this, but I am guessing it has something to do with a `1 -1 1 -1` sequence. Anyway, here is my code:

```
function orderArray (orderNum, array) {
   var orderNum_Array = [];

   for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
      if (Math.pow(-1, i +1) < 0) {
         array[i] = orderNum_Array [i];

         orderNum_Array[i] = orderNum_Array[i].toString();

         orderNum_Array.concat("a" + i);
      }else if (Math.pow(-1, i +1) > 0) {
         array[i] = orderNum_Array [i + 2];

         orderNum_Array[i + 2] = orderNum_Array[i + 2].toString();

         orderNum_Array.concat("a" + (i + 2));
      }
   }
}
```

Any and all help all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; The result I am trying to get is [1a1, 2a1, 3a2, 4a2, 5a3, 6a3] but any result like this would be greatly appreciated. I basically want to pair up the items in the array.

Comment: So, from an array like `[10, 5, 7, 9, 50, 66, 8,20]` you want to get an array like `['10a15', '7a29', '50a366', '8a420']`?

Comment: `Math.pow(-1, i +1) < 0` That's a novel way to check if a number is odd... Anyway, I think your code would be easier if you changed to looping by two elements at a time, ie `i += 2` instead of `i++`, but your requirements are a little unclear to me. Please illustrate with example input and output arrays.

Comment: @Geshode Is that the result you got? Thank you for that, now I (at least partially) know how to change my function. I want to pair up the numbers in an array: [1, 2, 3, 4] gives the result [1a1, 2a1, 3a2, 4a2].

Comment: What is the point of the `orderNum` parameter in your function?

Comment: The orderNum is for when I use the function multiple times; I want to create a new array each time. Each new array should be ordered with the ```orderNum```.

Comment: But how does it help you to accomplish that? Can you give us an example of how you intend to call the function with `orderNum` and the expected output?

Comment: Well, the resulting array should be labeled with ```orderNum``` in some way, but I am unsure of how incorporate ```orderNum``` into the name of the new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you are exceeding array bounds, most likely caused by `orderNum_Array[i + 2]`.

But you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this in a simpler way.

```js
function orderArray(array) {
   var num = 0;
   var orderNum_Array = array.map((item, index) => {
     if (index % 2 == 0) {
       num++;
     }
     return item + "a" + num;
   });
   
   return orderNum_Array;
}

console.log(orderArray([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the purpose of `orderNum` is, but as far as appending `a1, a2` at pairs of indices is concerned, you can make this concise by using [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```js
function orderArray(array) {
  return array.map((n, i) => `${n}a${Math.ceil((i + 1) / 2)}`)
}

console.log(orderArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```